# Check nodejs class optimisation

Tags: javascript, performance, node.js

i am new with nodejs, and i am trying to ameliorate, not only my experience but the power of my code, so i would like to ask you today to give :

some way to optimise my code
note on 10 (?? / 10) for my code
and if there is any website where i can test my code, i ll be so grateful
so here is my nodejs class.

there is no problem with the code itself but it looks like isn't professional

```
 const formidable = require('formidable'),
    jimp = require('jimp'),
    shortid = require('shortid'),
    validator = require('validator'),
    moment = require('moment'),
    ObjectId = require('mongodb').ObjectId,
    fs = require('fs'),
    dot = require('mongo-dot-notation'); // to update as an object

class AdminList {

    constructor(router) {
        router.post('/adminlist/ajouter', this.AjouterAdmin.bind(this));
        router.get('/adminList/recuperer', this.RecupererAdmin.bind(this));
        router.delete('/adminList/supprimer/:id', this.SupprimerAdmin.bind(this));
        router.get('/adminList/supprimer/:id', this.RecupererAdmin.bind(this));
        router.put('/adminList/modifier', this.ModifierAdmin.bind(this));
    }

    AjouterAdmin(req, res) {
        let form = new formidable.IncomingForm(),
            extensionList = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'tiff'],
            db = req.app.db, imgExtension;
        form.parse(req, async (err, fields, files) => {
            if (err) return (err);
            if (files.avatar) imgExtension = files.avatar.name.split('.').pop();
            switch (true) {
                case (fields.email === undefined || !validator.isEmail(fields.email)):
                    ErrorMessage("Format email invalid", res);
                    break;
                case (fields.dateNaissance === undefined || validator.toDate(fields.dateNaissance) === null):
                    ErrorMessage("Date de naissance invalid", res);
                    break;
                case (fields.phone === undefined || validator.isEmpty(fields.phone)):
                    ErrorMessage("Numéro de telephone invalid", res);
                    break;
                case (fields.adresse === undefined || !validator.isAlphanumeric(fields.adresse)):
                    ErrorMessage("L'adresse doit être alphanumérique", res);
                    break;
                case (fields.posteCode === undefined || !validator.isNumeric(fields.posteCode)):
                    ErrorMessage("Code postale invalid", res);
                    break;
                case (fields.displayName === undefined || validator.isEmpty(fields.displayName)):
                    ErrorMessage("Nom et prénom invalid", res);
                    break;
                case (fields.mdp === undefined || validator.isEmpty(fields.mdp)):
                    ErrorMessage("Mot de passe invalid", res);
                    break;
                case (fields.ville === undefined || validator.isEmpty(fields.ville)):
                    ErrorMessage("Ville invalid", res);
                    break;
                case (fields.pays === undefined || validator.isEmpty(fields.pays)):
                    ErrorMessage("Pays invalid", res);
                    break;
                case (files.avatar === undefined || !extensionList.includes(imgExtension)):
                    ErrorMessage("le type d'image doit être jgp/jpeg/png/tiff", res);
                    break;
                default:
                    db.collection("utilisateur").findOne({ email: fields.email }, { projection: { _id: 1 } }, (err, user) => {
                        if (err) ErrorMessage(err, res);
                        if (user)
                            ErrorMessage("Adresse email déja enregistrer", res);
                        else {
                            let newUser = createOrEditUser(fields, files, 'editeur', 'ajouter');
                            db.collection("utilisateur").insertOne(newUser, function (err) {
                                if (err) {
                                    res.writeHead(500, { 'content-type': 'text/plain' });
                                    res.end(err);
                                }
                                res.writeHead(200, { 'content-type': 'text/plain' });
                                res.end("success");
                            })
                        }
                    });
                    break;
            }
        });
    }

    RecupererAdmin(req, res) {
        let db = req.app.db;
        db.collection("utilisateur")
            .find({ "role": "editeur" }, { projection: { _id: 1, email: 1, name: 1, phone: 1, image: 1 } })
            .skip((req.params.page - 1) * 15)
            .limit(15)
            .sort({ "dateInsert": -1 })
            .toArray((err, admin) => {
                if (err) return res.json(err)
                return res.status(200).json(admin);
            });
    }

    SupprimerAdmin(req, res) {
        let db = req.app.db;
        db.collection("utilisateur").updateOne({ _id: ObjectId(req.params.id) }, { $set: { desactive: true } },
            (err) => {
                if (err) return res.json(err);
                return res.status(200).json({ message: "supprimer" });
            });
    }

    ModifierAdmin(req, res, cb) {
        let form = new formidable.IncomingForm(),
            extensionList = ['jpg', 'jpeg', 'png', 'tiff'],
            db = req.app.db, imgExtension;
        form.parse(req, async (err, fields, files) => {
            if (err) return (err);
            if (files.avatar) imgExtension = files.avatar.name.split('.').pop();
            switch (true) {
                case (fields.id === undefined):
                    ErrorMessage("id utilisateur invalid", res);
                case (fields.email !== undefined && !validator.isEmail(fields.email)):
                    ErrorMessage("Format email invalid", res);
                    break;
                case (fields.dateNaissance !== undefined && validator.toDate(fields.dateNaissance) === null):
                    ErrorMessage("Date de naissance invalid", res);
                    break;
                case (fields.phone !== undefined && validator.isEmpty(fields.phone)):
                    ErrorMessage("Numéro de telephone invalid", res);
                    break;
                case (fields.adresse !== undefined && !validator.isAlphanumeric(fields.adresse)):
                    ErrorMessage("L'adresse doit être alphanumérique", res);
                    break;
                case (fields.posteCode !== undefined && !validator.isNumeric(fields.posteCode)):
                    ErrorMessage("Code postale invalid", res);
                    break;
                case (fields.displayName !== undefined && validator.isEmpty(fields.displayName)):
                    ErrorMessage("Nom et prénom invalid", res);
                    break;
                case (fields.mdp !== undefined && validator.isEmpty(fields.mdp)):
                    ErrorMessage("Mot de passe invalid", res);
                    break;
                case (fields.ville !== undefined && validator.isEmpty(fields.ville)):
                    ErrorMessage("Ville invalid", res);
                    break;
                case (fields.pays !== undefined && validator.isEmpty(fields.pays)):
                    ErrorMessage("Pays invalid", res);
                    break;
                case (files.avatar !== undefined && !extensionList.includes(imgExtension)):
                    ErrorMessage("le type d'image doit être jgp/jpeg/png/tiff", res);
                    break;
                default:
                    UtilisateurExist(req, fields.email).then(async (result) => {
                        console.log('here');
                        if (result === true) {
                            ErrorMessage("Adresse email déjà utilisé", res);
                        } else {
                            let newUser = await createOrEditUser(fields, files, 'editeur', 'modifier');
                            db.collection("utilisateur").updateOne({ _id: ObjectId(fields.id) }, dot.flatten(newUser), (err, user) => {
                                if (err) ErrorMessage(err, res);
                                if (user.result.n === 0)
                                    ErrorMessage("Utilisateur n'existe pas", res);
                                else {
                                    res.writeHead(200, { 'content-type': 'text/plain' });
                                    res.end("success");
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    });
                    break;
            }
        });
    }
}
module.exports = AdminList;


function createOrEditUser(fields, files, role, type) {
    let newUser = {};
    if (fields.email) newUser.email = fields.email;
    if (fields.mdp) newUser.mdp = fields.mdp;
    if (fields.displayName) newUser.name = fields.displayName
    if (role !== undefined && type !== 'modifier') newUser.role = role;
    if (type === 'ajouter') newUser.dateInsert = moment().utc(1).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
    if (type === 'modifier') newUser.dateModif = moment().utc(1).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
    if (fields.dateNaissance) newUser.dateNaissance = fields.dateNaissance;
    if (fields.phone) newUser.phone = fields.phone
    if (fields.pays) newUser.pays = fields.pays
    if (fields.ville) newUser.ville = fields.ville
    if (fields.posteCode) newUser.posteCode = fields.posteCode
    if (fields.adresse) newUser.adresse = fields.adresse;
    if (fields.PhototoDelete === true) {
        fs.unlink(`../../ assets / img50 / ${fields.PhototoDelete}`);
        fs.unlink(`../../ assets / img140 / ${fields.PhototoDelete}`);
    }
    if (files.avatar) {
        imgExtension = files.avatar.name.split('.').pop();
        let imgName = generateImageName() + '.' + imgExtension;
        newUser.image = imgName;
        let imgSmallPath = `assets / img50 / ${imgName}`;
        let imgBigPath = `assets / img140 / ${imgName}`;
        genImgResize(files.avatar, imgBigPath, 140);
        genImgResize(files.avatar, imgSmallPath, 50);
    }
    return newUser;
}

function generateImageName() {
    return shortid.generate()
}

// 50* 50 image
function genImgResize(file, savePath, size) {
    return jimp.read(file.path, (err, img) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        img.resize(size, size)
            .quality(60)
            .write(`${savePath}`)
        return savePath
    }).catch(err => { return { err: err } });
}

function ErrorMessage(message, res) {
    res.writeHead(400, { 'content-type': 'text/plain' });
    res.end(message);
}

async function UtilisateurExist(req, email) {
    let db = req.app.db;
    let userExist = await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        db.collection("utilisateur").findOne({ email: email }, { projection: { _id: 1 } }, (err, user) => {
            if (err) reject(err);
            if (user) resolve(true)
            else resolve(false)
        });
    });
    return userExist
}
```